# In Power BI, how do I sum rows in a table up to the end of the previous week number for the current year?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table of sales data going back to 2021 and I want to calculate the current year sales up to the end of the previous week number.  I also have a Date-Dim table setup for the week number.

Whatever I try, I appear to get the right total value but when I display in a visual by customer account, I get issues.

I've tried using different DAX expressions that revolve around filtering 'total sales' by:

1. Week number < current week number
2. Current year.

Comment: Can you share what DAX expressions you have tried and what the output of each was?

Answer (score 0):

I want to calculate the current year sales up to the end of the previous week number.

CALCULATE([Total Sales],
FILTER('DimDate',[Year]=MAX('DimDate'[Year]) && [WeekNo] = MAX('DimDate'[WeekNo]) - 1)
)
?

Comment: Thanks for this, after a bit more playing around I realised it was the way I was referencing the date table.  I had a measure in there that was using the date table and because I was then filtering on date table with this calc (similar to your DAX) it was getting confused.  Changed the measure so it didn't use the date table and it worked.